# Canvas strokeStyle not changing in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to get a webpage screen saver working on windows 10, but it's using internet explorer :(

I want the color of a line to fade into the next color while being drawn. This works fine in Chrome, but in internet explorer the strokeStyle doesn't update on every step.

I've included a link to a snippet showing the issue:

```js
function colorTween(from, to, step, maxStep) {
    const newColor = [0,0,0,0];
    from.forEach(function (fromVal, i) {
        const toVal = to[i];
        newColor[i] = fromVal + (((toVal - fromVal)/maxStep)*step);
    });
    return newColor;
}

//init
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
ctx.lineWidth = 50;
ctx.lineCap = "round";

const fromColor = [0,0,0,1]; //black
const toColor = [255,255,255,1]; //white

const y = canvas.height/2;
let x = 0;
let prevX = 0;

//draw loop
setInterval(function () {
    //increase x
    x++;

    //get color fading into next color
    const drawColor = colorTween(fromColor, toColor, x, canvas.width);
      
    //draw line segment
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba("+drawColor[0]+","+drawColor[1]+","+drawColor[2]+","+drawColor[3]+")";

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    //setup for next loop
    prevX = x;
}, 1000/60);
```

```css
body, canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    overflow: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of a jsbin, edit your post, and use the `runnable snippet` option. Stackoverflow has "jsbin" built in. But note that IE has had pretty solid Canvas2D support since IE9, so you're almost certainly going to have to run through the [mcve] exercise first, to whittle your code down to exactly _only_ enough to show off the thing that isn't working. And it's probably not the strokeStyle attribute itself (good chance that while running through the MCVE exercise, you discover the _real_ problem all on your own).

Comment: Try to `.toFixed(2)` the values in your `colorTween` function, IIRC IE does choke on `rgba(r,g,b,0.verylongdecimalnumberhere)`.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, that was exactly the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer did choke on too decimal numbers in RGB CSS values (`strokeStyle` is parsed as a CSS <color> value).
Your `colorTween` function will very likely produce such decimal numbers and IE will just ignore the value entirely.

To avoid that, round your R, G, and B values, and while I'm not sure it's needed, you may want to also call `.toFixed()` on the Alpha value (for R,G,B the decimal is anyway discarded by implementations, and for alpha the maximum granularity is 1/256, i.e ~0.004).

```js
from.forEach(function (fromVal, i) {
  const toVal = to[i];
  const newVal = fromVal + (((toVal - fromVal)/maxStep)*step);
  newColor[i] = i===3 ? newVal.toFixed(3) : Math.round(newVal);
```

Comment: Thanks, I also had decimals on the rgb values; resulting from the division in my tween function. Having ANY decimal places on the rgb values also causes the strokeStyle (and I assume fillStyle too?) to not update on internet explorer.

Comment: and having a limited number of decimal on R,G,B is fine or does this need to be an int? I can't remember and don't have access to IE right now.

Comment: It only worked when R,G,B values were ints. Also, after testing it, I found I don't need .toFixed(3) for the alpha value to work in ie11; Just need to make sure the RGB values are ints!
`ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba("+Math.round(drawColor[0])+","+Math.round(drawColor[1])+","+Math.round(drawColor[2])+","+drawColor[3].toFixed(3)+")";`

Comment: Alright, I'll revise my answer later on, thanks for the feedback